# How do I determine orthonormalbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra

On the vector space $C\left [ a,b \right ]$ (set of continuous functions $f:\left [ a,b \right ]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$) defines

$\left \langle f,g \right \rangle:=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx$

a scalar product. How do I determine orthonormalbasis with the Orthonormalization method of Gram and Schmidt of the functions $f_1(x)=1, f_2(x)=x, f_3(x)=x^2.$

Lets say that I need to find orthonormal basis $\left (e_1,e_2,e_3  \right )$.

$e_1=\frac{f_1(x)}{\sqrt{\left \langle f_1,f_1 \right \rangle}}$ Correct?

$e_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{?}}$

I don't know which value should be in my root?

What should I do with this integral??

Comment: What is the domain of these functions?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ ??

Comment: If you are defining the inner product on the vector space $C [a,b]$ then it isn't $\mathbb R$.

Comment: By definition, $\langle f_1, f_1 \rangle = \langle 1, 1 \rangle = \int_a^b (1)(1) dx = b - a$.

Comment: so my vector $e_1=\frac{1}{b-a}$ or?

Comment: @Travis is this good?

Comment: According to your formula, $e_1 = \frac{f_1(x)}{\sqrt{\langle f_1, f_1\rangle}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b - a}}$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot root, thank you.